# Where to define AllDisjointClasses in Protege

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, rdfs

i m learning owl and i see example in https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/

`[]  rdf:type     owl:AllDisjointClasses ;
     owl:members  ( :Woman  :Man ) .`

wonder where to define AllDisjointClasses on protege class view?

there's a Disjoint With on each class's description view, is this the same thing?

and when i put that statement in turtle syntax than open the source file, the protege throw an error dialog.

Comment: Yes, the same, but `owl:disjointWith` is only for two class expressions. Can you try `[ a owl:AllDisjointClasses ; 
  owl:members ( :Woman :Man ) 
] .` ? It is seems to be a OWLAPI4 bug, which is used by Protege: both constructions are valid N3 and Turtle (there is also an open issue https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/issues/775 , but it seems the description is wrong now, it is fixed in Turtle 2013)

Comment: @ssz it works. and the view show disjointWith on description view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`members` are elements of a [RDF Collection](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#rdf-collections). So adding the statements by hand is not easy as only two statements.

Here is an example in Turtle serialisation:

```
[ rdf:type owl:AllDisjointClasses ;
  owl:members ( :URI1
                :URI2
                :URI3
              )
] .
```

Here is the same example in XML serialisation:

```
<rdf:Description>
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AllDisjointClasses"/>
  <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="URI1"/>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="URI2"/>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="URI3"/>
  </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
```

In Protégé, the simpliest way to achieve this is to define a class as disjoint with other Classes in the Class Hierarchy tab (holding CTRL pressed allow you to add multiple elements to the collections).

Comment: i've save a "RDF/XML SYNTAX" but, this is not like ssz's turtle syntax, but i think i might input it in wrong way.    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-22#Man"/>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-22#Woman"/>
    </owl:members>

Comment: I edited the answer to provide you Turtle serialisation.

Answer (score 1):

There is now (protégé 5.5.0) a `Disjoint Union Of` option in the Classes view. It is the last one below `Disjoint With`. [Disjoint Union Of in Protégé class view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILTSG.png)